# .remove(word) gives "not in the list" right after a check for that word

Tags: python, pandas, runtime-error

I already ran this code before, and I am confident the error is not due to some other code part failing. I am writing a parser that iterates over every row in a dataframe and parses a string into multiple columns in the output dataframe. I recently added a new couple of lines inside a for loop:

```
for word in words:
    word = word.replace("-", " ")
    if word in measurement_units:
        measurement = word
        words.remove(word)
```

The only added thing is the if statement and what comes after it. Now, my code errors with

```
    words.remove(word)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

The error is not common, it goes hundreds of thousands of rows before giving this error, so it cannot be something completely trivial - some type of string clearly triggers it. I am a total beginner, so I already asked bing AI and it wants me to write it as:

```
words = row.split(" ")
new_words = []
for word in words:
    word = word.replace("-", " ")
    if word not in measurement_units:
        new_words.append(word)
    else:
        measurement = word
    words = new_words
```

Which works, but why do I need to? In my mind, this already should not be happening - we know the word exists, since the "if" statement already implicitly checks if its "", and there is no removal done between the if and the `words.remove`. What gives?

Not much - there is only so many test you can write in a 2-line snippet, and since I have well over a million rows, printing every row or every word is not feasible.

Comment: You're checking if the word is in one list, but attempting to remove it from a different list.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour] and [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If word contained '-' then the modified word (i.e., '-' replaced by ' ') may no longer exist in the words list. Also, you should not be trying to modify a list while enumerating it. Maybe you should clarify your objective with some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 1):

Without any sample data to verify this against it looks like you want:

```
for word in words[:]:
    if word.replace('-', ' ') in measurement_units:
        words.remove(word)
```

Comment: Exactly this. Don't try to mutate a list that you're iterating over. You'll get unexpected behavior (like this!)

Comment: @AdamSmith This code does **not** modify the list that's being enumerated

Comment: no of course yours doesn't -- OP's does (`for word in words: ... words.remove(word)`)